# Checking if a function is one-one(injective)

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

So I have this function:

$\dfrac{x^2-2}{x^2+2x}$ and im supposed to find if it is one-one.

I've tried taking out the drivative of it and check if its $>0$ or $<0$ but im facing trouble there.

I've also heard that you can do it with a graph but I'm looking for a more algebraic approach than a geometric one?

Isn't there a sureshot way of finding out if a function is one one or not?

Answer (score 5):

Consider, for example,  the equation $f(x)=2$. This gives $x^{2}-2=2(x^{2}+2x)$ or $x^{2}+4x+2=0$. There are two solutions of this quadratic: $x =-2\pm \sqrt 2$. Hence $f$ is not injective.
In fact, every value in the range of $f$ except $1$ is attained at exactly two points whereas the value $1$ is attained only at $x=-1$.

Comment: I like this solution. And here is how you generalize it: plot the curve and simply look on it if it looks injective or not. If not, try to guess a y-coordinate which appears at least twice. Then, use the approach in the answer. The nice thing is that plotting is always a good idea since it provides intuition, and you can often use this intuition to simply guess a solution.

Comment: To add to the comment by Engineer trying math it is better not to start differentiating when you have simple expression like this. Try applying the definition: $f$ is injective iff $f(x)=y$ has no solution or exactly one solution for every $y$.

Answer (score 1):

This is all false. The if-statement fails. Kavi Rama Murthy's answer is correct.

Such a function would be injective if and only if it was strictly monotone in its domain. When we take $f'$, we get
$$\frac{2x(x^2+2x) - (2x+2)(x^2-2)}{(x^2+2x)^2}  = \frac{2x^2 + 4x + 4}{(x^2+2x)^2}$$
Determine domain of $f$ and see if it's either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing in the whole domain by the above.

---

Here's my failure.
**Theorem**. Let $f:D\to\mathbb R$, where $D\subseteq \mathbb R$ is **connected**. Then $f$ is injective if  $f'>0$ or $f'<0$ (in $D$).

The domain for the function in question is not connected, hence the theorem is inapplicable.

Comment: Unfortunately, $2x^2+4x+4=2\big((x+1)^2+1\big)$, so the derivative is positive everywhere that it’s defined. It’s injective on $(\leftarrow,-2)\cup(0,\to)$ and on $(-2,0)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Uhh, so the  if part is wrong.

Comment: Yes. When there are breaks in the domain, the function ‘gets a fresh start’. Think of the tangent function for an even more extreme example.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for pointing that out. Is it true then for connected domains? I don't actually want to delete the answer, since it's a nice example of "not checking theorem assumptions" and getting punished for it.

Comment: Yes, if the domain were connected, and the derivative were, say, positive over the whole domain, then we could conclude that the function was strictly increasing over the domain and hence injective.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I edited the answer. Is it reasonable to leave an answer undeleted, when it's wrong with an explanation where I went wrong?

Comment: I think that it’s a useful answer; I would go ahead and leave it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a much simpler method to check whether a function is one-one or not.

As we know a one-one function can be defined as function from A to B such that each element of Set A has a unique element on Set B.

Whenever f(x)=f(y), then x=y

And equivalently, if x ≠ y, then f(x) ≠ f(y)

Formally, it is stated as, if f(x)=f(y)  implies x=y, then f is one-to-one mapped or f is 1-1.

Now we take two elements $x_1$ and $x_2$ and assume that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ and ultimately prove that $x_1 = x_2$ only then can we prove that the given function is one-one.

You may refer this - [How to determine if a function is one-to-one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101975/how-to-determine-if-a-function-is-one-to-one)

Answer (score 0):

Whether a function is injective (one-one) essentially requires a domain $A$ and r ange $B$ like $f:A \to B$., without this specification the question does not arise.
The natural domain of $f(x)=\frac{x^2-2}{x(x+2)}$ is $\Re -\{0, -2\}$.
Next, monotonicity of $f(x)$ is decided if  is $f'(x)$ is positive-definite or negative-definite is decide by $f'(x)>0 or <0.$ So here $$ f'(x)=\frac{2[(x+1)^2+1]}{x^2(x+2)^2}>0.$$ So it is a increasing function in three  largest domains: $$D_1=(-\infty, -2),~ D_2=(-2,0), ~ D_3 =(0,\infty).$$
Hence it is injective in tjese three largest domains. See $f(x)$ in the Fig. below:

[image]